# Get a Report xml by id

Tags: reports-api

In this URL: https://.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ReportList

I get a list on reports, example:

[image]

but... how i can acces to one specific report by ID?

My objetive is print a specific report in my application.

Comment: You can get json easily, why xml ?

Comment: yes, with $reportsxml = simplexml_load_string($data);

Comment: It does not answer my que. Analtycs api of salesforce provides response in json, you can digest the reponse in json and use it ...easily.

Comment: ummm i dont know how to do it :/ can you give me example?

Comment: David has added the same one already.

Answer (score 0):

The [Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/) provides a variety of endpoints to support your external applications in consuming report data.

To consume and render the data for a single report, you will probably want to call the [Execute Sync](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getreportrundata.htm) endpoint:

> `/services/data/<latest API version>/analytics/reports/<report ID>`

This will return a fairly complicated data structure called a *fact map* (described in the documentation linked) that you can interpret to reproduce the detail data and groupings that would be present in the report as rendered in Salesforce.